# Can the word 'only' be used to emphasize the doer of the action as in below ideas?

Tags: word-usage

I'm from India and I hear the following expressions using the word 'only' to emphasize the doer of the action as
I only repaired it (to say I repaired it and nobody else) or, He only broke the toys.
She only informed all.

Is the above usage acceptable? plz update

Comment: In some contexts you could put _only_ before the subject - 'Only he broke the toys' - but it would be much more natural in everyday speech to say 'He was the only one who broke the toys'.

Comment: You can use **alone** this way in American English, like "He *alone* broke the toys" to mean "He and nobody else broke the toys", but **only** is not used this way in AE.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how "only" would be understood in British English.

Only is an adverb in "I only repaired it", and it means "I didn't do anything else to it except the repair."  I would understand, in context, that it means "I didn't make it.", or perhaps "I didn't break it!"

Stress and emphasis, and a pragmatic interpretation can apply.  So "He only broke the toys." would probably imply that there was something else broken that he didn't break, or some other damage which he wasn't responsible for.  "He only broke the toys, he didn't smash the window or steal the money."

So does not have the meaning "alone" in Standard British English, and I don't think it is acceptable in American English either.

Comment: I would understand "I only repaired it" to mean "I wasn't the one that broke it- I just repaired it" ;-)

Comment: Yes, the American English meaning is much the same as what you describe.

Comment: Be aware that the word "only" is a creeper. It tends to be used towards the start of a sentence when it is intended to modify an element much further along. "I only saw him with the policeman chasing him, shouting at him to stop, as he ran from the shop clutching a parcel."

Comment: A big thank for the update. in that case plz suggest if the following usage is correct.I alone informed them. They alone pressed me to accompany the group.

Comment: "I alone" seems reasonable, as emphasis.  "They alone" seems an oxymoron, since "they" implies plural, and "alone" implies singular.